# Trying to find diaper cover with wipeable exterior

Tags: cloth-diaper

Trying to find diaper covers (for cloth diapers) which are made of a fabric or material which can be wiped off. The ones I've seen on Amazon or other websites seem to all be made with a cotton or wool exterior, which would be absorbent -- seems like that would easily get messed up, so that's why I'm looking for something wipeable (nylon or something like that).

Thanks for any light you can shed on this question.

Comment: Not an answer, but I would question your need for wipeable outside of diaper covers. PUL covers are wipeable on the inside which suffices for most of the time. If they are just peed on they can be dried and reused and if more lands on them just put them in the washing machine (or wash them through by hand). Depending on how often you wash 5-6 covers will be enough. Speaking from experience.

Comment: To continue from what @Lehue has said, the reason why these wipable covers are so hard to come by is because anything waterproof doesn't breathe. It makes wearing it for long periods very uncomfortable. PUL is probably they closest you're going to get.

Comment: @Lehue Thanks a lot for your comments, that clarifies the issue for me. I appreciate your help.